# Getting null from 'getLatitude' Maps Android Studio

Tags: java, android, null, maps

I recently started using Android Studio, and I'm just starting with the basics.
I tried to load in a google maps page, which is working fine. However, whenever I try to load in my location, i get a Null error:
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.wakelicious.MYPROJECTNAME.MapsActivity.setUpMap(MapsActivity.java:71)

Here is my MapsActivity:

```
package com.example.wakelicious.MYPROJECTNAME;

import com.example.wakelicious.MYPROJECTNAME.util.MyCurrentLocationListener;
import com.example.wakelicious.MYPROJECTNAME.util.SystemUiHider;

import android.content.Context;
import android.provider.SyncStateContract;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.LocationSource;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;
private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;
private static final boolean TOGGLE_ON_CLICK = true;
private static final int HIDER_FLAGS = SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

private SystemUiHider mSystemUiHider;
private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
private TextView latituteField;
private TextView longitudeField;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}
private void setUpMap() {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_LOW);
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());

    latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
    latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            CameraPosition myPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(new LatLng(51.5736359, 5.0386894)).zoom(13).build();
    mMap.animateCamera(
            CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(myPosition));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.tilburg)).position(new LatLng(51.5736359, 5.0386894)).title("Tilburg"));
}

}
```

And in my Manifest i've added the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I honestly don't know what is going wrong. I've turned on the GPS on my phone, and I even get a blue orb (my last known location, after i opened google maps) in the app with my location, but somehow I can't get the info from that location.

Does anyone know where I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting null because you're location has not been queried yet. As the method name implies, getLastKnownLocation, retrieves the **last known** location. Enabling GPS is not enough, you need to query for your location first.

What you want to do is to fetch the location if it's not yet present:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    private LocationManager mLocManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mLocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_LOW);
        String provider = mLocManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        Location location = mLocManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if (location == null) {
            mLocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, );
        } else {
            setLat(location);
        }
    }

    private void setLat(Location location) {
        TextView latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
        latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            setLat(location);
            mLocManager.removeUpdates(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I too face the same problem. i have changed my criteria accuracy and my problem get solved.

criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

or  criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);